# Exclude directories from PHP CS Fixer analisys in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, php-cs-fixer

I have multiple sub-projects inside a main project, and just one works fine with PHP CS Fixer.

Is it possible to exclude certain directories from PHP CS Fixer in PhpStorm 2023.1.2?

Comment: As far as I remember PHP CS Fixer (as well as other Code Quality tools), they are integrated as Inspections (the internal stuff used to display the result of analysis: warnings/errors/etc). Since it's an Inspection ... you can create **custom Scope** that will include only desired folders/files and add that scope in the corresponding inspection -- enable the inspection for this scope and disable for the rest. Try it.

Comment: It seems working, thanks a lot! Scopes are a very powerful but hidden PhpStorm feature.

Comment: BTW -- is it yours? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72754

Comment: No, but it confirms that your solution is the right one. If you want to write it as an answer I will be happy to upvote and mark as the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP CS Fixer (as well as other Code Quality tools), they report the results back to the IDE using the Inspections mechanics. Since it's an inspection, it means that you can use scopes...

From https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-inspection.html

> Inspections can scan your code in all project files **or only in specific scopes** (for example, only in production code or in modified files).

**So what you can do is:**

1. Create a [custom Scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/settings-scopes.html) that will include only desired folders/files.
2. Add that scope in the corresponding inspection: enable it for that scope and disable for Everything else.

[image]

*(The image is taken from a similar [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-72754). It's not exactly what I'm talking here but very close and gives clear idea on how it should be done)*